# Suppress repeated VSCode Install and Sync extension prompt

Tags: visual-studio-code

As soon as I connect to a remote environment using VSCode, it prompts me to install and sync any missing extension which is good, but it prompts for EVERY single extension repeatedly. I can't seem to find a way to do this only once.

Does anyone how there is a global setting anywhere to do this silently?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to conflict with the default vscode sync. disable vscode sync first then the Download setting once again